# How to show MySQL results in a table format when I execute queries from a text file?

Tags: mysql, sql

At this moment if I execute my SQL script file from terminal the output like below (Output 1):

```
mysql> sudo mysql  < sql_command.sql
ID  LastName    FirstName   Age
3   islam   saiful  23
4   NULL    sytul   40
5   NULL    Jakir   40
9   NULL    manus   NULL
90  NULL    manus   NULL
```

However, my expected result is (Output 2):

```
mysql> select * from Persons;
+----+----------+-----------+------+
| ID | LastName | FirstName | Age  |
+----+----------+-----------+------+
|  3 | islam    | saiful    |   23 |
|  4 | NULL     | sytul     |   40 |
|  5 | NULL     | Jakir     |   40 |
|  9 | NULL     | manus     | NULL |
| 90 | NULL     | manus     | NULL |
+----+----------+-----------+------+
```

The first result does not show the rows and columns in the right position. Please see the last column field "Age". Its values do not appear under Age.
How can I achieve output2?

Comment: 1) avoid screenshots

Comment: @eshirvana Thank you for your valuable information.

Comment: but also I don;t see any difference between first result and second! so not sure what's your question exactly ? try to explain

Comment: @eshirvana The first result does not show the rows and columns in the right position. Please see the last column field "Age". Its values do not appear under Age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**MySQL 8:**
Add this command line option: `--result-format=table`

**MySQL 5.7**
Add this command line option: `-t`

Comment: After adding --result-format=table it show output :mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'result-format=table'

Where I will add --result-format=table please clarify.

Comment: start mysql shell with `mysql --result-format=table`

Comment: It show [ERROR] unknown variable 'result-format=table'

Comment: I don't know your mysql version, maybe `mysql -t`?

Comment: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.35, for Linux (x86_64). 
mysql -t work fine. Thank you.

Comment: Good to hear, I will edit my answer, because `--result-format=table` is for MySQL 8.